# Calulate opposite vector as dot product (Householder QR decomposition)

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

This is not a homework question. I am working on the Householder QR decomposition, and trying to express (and understand the reason why) the orthogonal unit vector to the "mirror" subspace $\bf u$ can be used to calculate the vector $\bf w$ in the diagram below, as dot products of $\bf u$ and $\bf x$, working with real valued vectors.

[image]

---

NOTE to "self":

An easy way to look at it is as follows:

[image]

Since the projection $\bf P$ of $\bf x$ on $\bf u$ is a scalar multiple of $\bf u$, and the projection coincides with $\bf w$, we have $\bf P = u \, \alpha$, and $\bf u$ is orthogonal to the difference between $\bf x$ and $\bf P$. It follows that $0= \bf u^T\,(\bf x - \bf P) = u^T\,(\bf x - \bf u\,\alpha)$. Therefore,

$$\alpha = \frac{\bf u^T \bf x}{\bf u^T \bf u}$$

And substituting,

$$\bf P = \bf w = \bf u \, \alpha = \frac{\bf u\,\bf u^T}{\bf u^T \bf u} \bf x$$

If $\bf u$ is of unit length, $\bf w = \bf u\,\bf u^T  \, \bf x = \bf u^T \bf x \bf u$

And (for completeness),

[image]

$$\bf z = \bf x -  w = \bf x - u^T x u$$

and

$$\bf y = x -  2\,w= x  -2\, u^T x u = x  -2\,  uu^T x = (I - 2\,  uu^T)\,x$$

with the matrix $\bf H = I - 2\,uu^T$ being the mirror or reflexion matrix (aka a Householder transformation).

Since in the $\bf QR$ decomposition we want $\bf R$ to be upper triangular, each vector in the columns of $\bf R$ will be of the form $\bf y=\begin{bmatrix}y_i&0&0&\cdots&0\end{bmatrix}$, we want a "mirror" such that the projection is along $e_1$ and (being a mirror image) of length $||\bf x||$:

[image]

Given the equal norm of both $\bf x$ and $\bf y$, and the fact that there is only one non-zero entry in $\bf y$ (the first entry), $\bf y= \begin{bmatrix} \pm \lVert x\rVert&0&0&\cdots&0\end{bmatrix}$, and

$$\bf v=y -x=\pm \lVert x \rVert \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\\vdots\\x_m\end{bmatrix} $$

Having figured out $\bf v$ thus, we know that $\bf u= \frac{v}{\lVert v \rVert}$, which is what we needed to apply the Householder transformation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just orthogonal projection. If $\hat{\mathbf u}_1, \dots, \hat{\mathbf u}_n$ is an orthonormal basis (found via Gram-Schmidt) of the space $U$ depicted, then $\mathbf w$ is the projection of $\mathbf x$ onto $U$, which is given by
\begin{equation}
\mathbf w = \operatorname{proj}_U \mathbf x = \sum_{i=1}^n (\mathbf x \cdot \hat{\mathbf u}_i) \hat{\mathbf u}_i.
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
If the case you have in mind is exactly what's depicted (in $\mathbb R^2$), then $U = \operatorname{span} \mathbf u$ is the span of the single vector $\mathbf u$, and the orthonormal basis is just $\hat{\mathbf u}_1 = \frac{\mathbf u}{\| \mathbf u \|}$, in which case 
\begin{equation}
\mathbf w = \left( \mathbf x \cdot \frac{\mathbf u}{\| \mathbf u\|} \right) \frac{\mathbf u}{\| \mathbf u\|} = \frac{\mathbf x \cdot \mathbf u}{\mathbf u \cdot \mathbf u} \mathbf u.
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

Comment: Can you express $w$ directly as for products of $u$ and $x$?

Comment: Can you please add it to your answer just considering the plane for illustration? I'll be more than happy to accept the answer then.

Comment: I edited my answer -- hopefully now it's what you're looking for. Let me know if not!

Comment: Sorry to insist, but you are carrying out the dot product of x times the unitary u, and then sitting again with u?

Comment: I'm taking the dot product of $\mathbf x$ and the unit vector $\hat{\mathbf u}_i$ to give me a *number*; then i multiply this number by the vector $\hat{\mathbf u}_i$. Adding up the results for $i = 1, \dots, n$ gives the *vector* $\mathbf w$.

Comment: Last question... So the hat in the $\bf \hat u$ means normalized to length 1, and the adding up across different $i$ components is implicitly done in the dot product, so that the last equation is valid for all dimensions?

Comment: That's right -- the hat is just notation to mean that $\hat{\mathbf u}_i$ has unit length. But by, for example, $\hat{\mathbf u}_1$ and $\hat{\mathbf u}_2$, I mean two different vectors, *not* the first two coordinates of the same vector. $i$ counts the dimension of the subspace $U$; each of the vectors is in some larger space with dimension greater than $\dim U$. I have not written out individual coordinates of vectors (like you might write in defining/computing the dot product) anywhere.

Comment: My equation $(2)$ and your last displayed equation are the same. Note that $\mathbf x \cdot \mathbf u = \mathbf u ^{\mathrm{T}} \mathbf x$.

Comment: That would make it $\bf u^T \bf x \bf u$, which is different from my expression: $\bf u \bf u^T \bf x$

Comment: I didn't give a derivation of my $(2)$. Instead, I meant it as a special case of $(1)$, which I also didn't derive, but it's the standard "orthogonal projection" result in linear algebra. Note that $\mathbf u ^T \mathbf x \mathbf u$ and $\mathbf u \mathbf u^T \mathbf x$ are equal. You can always do the $\mathbf u ^T \mathbf x$ first, and this is just a scalar, which multiplies $\mathbf u$.